# Calculate angle of two points on Line chart

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I want to get the angle of two points on a Line chart. 
I know how to calculate an angle, the problem is that I need the x and y of the seriescollection.point and I have no idea how to get it.

Can someone help me with it?

EDIT:

Jean-François Corbett showed me how to get the points, I meant from top and left, and not point on the graph (on X scale and Y scale) though it can work.
I calculate it wrong. how can I calculate the angles in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: Wait a minute... by "x and y" of the point, you mean the point's *pixel* coordinates as shown on the screen?

Comment: Yes. but It can work with the coodinates on the x scale and y scale.

Comment: Well, that's what I gave you the first time around. Anyway, I edited my answer to give the pixel coordinates as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask how to get the (x,y) coordinates of points in a chart series. Here is how:

```
Dim c As Chart
Dim s As Series
Dim x As Variant
Dim y As Variant

Set c = ActiveChart
Set s = c.SeriesCollection.Item(1)

x = s.XValues
y = s.Values
```

**EDIT** As far as I can tell from the edited question, OP now wants the *pixel* coordinates of each point, with origin at the top left of the plot. To do so, you just need to scale by the axis width and span. The x axis is a bit tricky in the case of line plots (which I hate), because there is no min or max scale property; have to use the number of "categories" instead. The following code does this scaling:

```
Dim c As Chart
Dim s As Series
Dim xa As Axis
Dim ya As Axis
Dim x As Variant
Dim y As Variant
Dim i As Long

Set c = ActiveChart
Set s = c.SeriesCollection.Item(1)
Set xa = c.Axes(xlCategory)
Set ya = c.Axes(xlValue)

x = s.XValues
y = s.Values
For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
    ' Scale x by number of categories, equal to UBound(x) - LBound(x) + 1
    x(i) = (i - LBound(x) + 0.5) / (UBound(x) - LBound(x) + 1) * xa.Width
    ' Scale y by axis span
    y(i) = ya.Height - y(i) / (ya.MaximumScale - ya.MinimumScale) * ya.Height
Next i
```

Note that `y` increases along the negative y direction on the plot, since you want the origin to be at the top left.

Using this `x` and `y`, you can calculate your angle as seen on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The `X` and `Y` values are not directly accessible from the `Point` object, (as best as I can tell), but they represent actual values passed to the graph. Try accessing them from the worksheet where they are stored.

If that is unavailable, try `Series.values`, which returns an array of Y-values, and `Series.XValues`, which returns an array of X-values. (See [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238636%28v=office.12%29.aspx))

Comment: What does it mean to access them from the worksheet? I dont what you are talking about and how to do it. about the second optional solution - I read about it before and its kinda messy/hard - I am pretty sure some1 already did it. I just cant find it in the internet :|

Comment: Well, Excel charts are typically produced from data stored on worksheets. The easiest thing to do would be to calculate the angles on the worksheet with the data used for the chart.

Comment: Using `series.values` shouldn't be difficult. It should return a two-dimensional array, such that `array(1,2)` is the second value from the first data point (or maybe the array will begin with (0,0) - hard to know without trying it).

Comment: u mean the second value from the first seriescollection, right? and thats not the purpose. I want to get the point on the graph > left and top. Btw I thought about another solution - to add empty datalabel, use xlLabelPositionCenter and take the left + top of it... but I am not sure about this solution

Comment: No, I mean the second value from the first row of data. `SeriesCollection` holds each `Series` object for the chart, and each `Series` object has a `Values` property containing the actual data in each series.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're looking for. Do you mean the point furthest to the top right of the chart?